# Scroll to top does not work in React after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a long list of categories and on select (click) the categories are substituted by actual items (categories contain items). What I want to do is scroll to top on category select but it does not work for some reason. Here is what I have so far:

```js
const scrollToTop = () => {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
};

export const CategoryCard = (props) => {

const onCategorySelect = () => {
  scrollToTop();
}

return ({isCategoryType(item) ? (
  <div
    onClick={() => {
      onCategorySelect();
    }}
   >
    <Typography
      onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
    > Category one </Typography>
   </div>) : (...)
})
```

Comment: Are you sure the element you are using scroll to is scrollable

Comment: Oh, maybe because I'm doing it from the card component, while it should be higher up the dom tree

Comment: Yes try to target the cards container in the dom

Comment: I tried moving it higher up the dom, in the component that renders all cards but still does not work. Anyone else has some ideas?

Comment: Also tried adding a ref to the root `div` and `rootRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0);`. Did not work as well :(

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't find a way to do it with refs no I insrted a dummy `<div id="top" />` and used `document.getElementById("top").scrollIntoView();`.